# Does intel i5 3210M support vt-d?

Tags: vt-d

Different sockets has different features

BGA house
http://ark.intel.com/products/65708

rPGA housing
http://ark.intel.com/products/67355

Compare chart:
http://ark.intel.com/compare/67355,65708

VT-d seems cool feature for me especially for graphics visualization.
I am buying new laptop and I would like to know if processor supports this feature.
I think it is this laptop, but i am not sure:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03315668

Comment: BGA is not a socketed processor, but a solder on processor, and is not used in most PC's.

Comment: That HP uses a socketed processor so it will be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does support VT-d. Look [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/65708/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-%283M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz%29-BGA?wapkw=3210m)

Comment: but if you choose different packing you get no

Comment: google search on "g6-2007er bga" returns a long list of pages while the search on "g6-2007er rpga" returns just one page as a side effect. Did I convince you?

Comment: Info on ark is corect, and response from Intel is that support for VT-d is up to OEM no matter whatch chip you get. I